# Maven actionbarsherlock - Theme resources are not available

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, themes

I started using maven on ADT. I spent a day and most problems are resolved but I got stuck in a strange problem.

ActionBarSherlock is correctly integrated and I can use all classes provided by the library, but I cannot use the Themes of ABS on styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml.

Dependency at pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Also tried:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
```

The actionbarsherlock library is linked successfully so I can see actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.jar on Maven Dependencies on Java Build Path. I can access the classes from ABS, and can run *mvn clean install* and *mvn android:run* without any problem:

However, I cannot use the themes; for example:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
...
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Eclipse shows error messages like following:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar').
```

I am using:

- android-maven-plugin 3.6.0
- maven 3.0.5 (I also tried maven 3.1.1)
- jdk 1.7

I tried a lot of approaches found on the web but couldn't resolve this problem. Could you help me..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did your solve this problem? If yes, please post how you did. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">`

should be

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">`

(i.e.: with the "@style/" before the name of the parent theme).

Hope this helps